# Javascript in anchor href: get reference to "calling" anchor tag

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="javascript: get_a_reference_to_the_a_tag.doSomethingWithIt();">...
```

Is there I way to get a reference to the anchor tag in the href javascript without adding an id to the anchor tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `this` to the function call, but you'll need to do it `onclick`, otherwise, `this` will reference the `Window`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="yourfunction(this)">...</a>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/tavifuputa/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `this` inside the function you are using. `this` is the reference to the element itself.

EDIT: Saw the href call too late, i thought he was using onclick. Anyways, a working example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction(this);">This is the anchor tag</a>
<script>
function myFunction(anchor) {
    console.log(anchor.innerHTML); // output: This is the anchor tag
}
</script>
```

Comment: huh? `this` won't be the element inside onclick function. There is more to it than answer implies and as it stands this answer is incorrect

Comment: It will refer to the window.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add identifiers as a class name or a data attribute that you can use as selectors from your javascript (ids are not the best practice). If you really want to use your href tag as a selector though you can.

HTML:

```
<a href="a_link_here">
```

JS:

```
var myAnchorTag = document.querySelector('[href=a_link_here]')
console.log(myAnchorTag) //your element
console.log(myAnchorTag.href) //'a_link_here'
```